# How to track email interactions?

Tags: email, tracking, html-email

I am creating a HTML email that i will send to all my clients, this email contains text, images, and links.

I want to keep track of this email and collect some information about it.
Until now i can retrieve the open rate, and the most clicked links, but i also want to know how many 
people have scrolled down to the bottom of the email, supposedly meaning that the entire content has been read.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check only customers that open your email with images.. you can linked images from your script pages and check how customers opened email.. it`s only way for collecting information about reading email .. javascript can not used in email then you cant find who peoples scroll down and read all your text